# 3D objects with animated bones Monogame in the year 2017, is it possible?

Tags: c#, 3d, monogame, monogame-extended

I've been working on a game for quite some time now and suddenly it seems that I've hit the great wall of..

In the earlier XNA there were possibilities to use animation exported with the 3D object .fbx files, but this was in the old XNA with SkinningData and AnimationPlayer etc.

I can't use these old samples that I've found on the Internet.
How can I in the year 2017 animate an animated 3D object exported from Blender .fbx animate it in Monogame by the use of them bones?

I'm using Monogame in C# VS2017 but the Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Processors and everything else doesn't exist.

The closest thing to an animation that I've made is to split up my object into pieces in Blender and animate each part with CreateTranslation and CreateRotation.. But that's old school to do it that way.

Or, I misunderstood the whole thing?

- I'm not going to use Unity.

Answer (score 5):

Finally I've found the solution to my problem.

First I've created a new content pipeline by following this blog: http://community.monogame.net/t/tutorial-how-to-get-xnas-skinnedsample-working-with-monogame/7609

You will not need the special Blender plugin/extension to be able to export to XNA/Monogame, you can use the ordinary FBX exporter. Instead of Apply Scale "All Local" change to "All FBX" and much about everything will work when importing it into the pipline tool.

Sometimes some certain things will be deformed anyway but that's the way it's always been.